# GitLab CI/CD job without pulling LFS files?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, git-lfs

When our GitLab CI/CD job runs, it first pulls a Docker image and then git clones the entire repo.  Afterwards, the Build commands are executed in the Docker image, etc.

Is it possible to only clone the **non**-LFS files from the repo?  ... Or perhaps clone the HEAD of the master branch from only a specific subdirectory and it's subdirectories, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, full cloning of LFS files can be restricted!  By default, GitLab will clone your repo into the CI/CD build directory.  To limit the clone from downloading the LFS files, tell it not to do it.  You do this by setting a variable in `.gitlab-ci.yml` like this.

```
# Other declarations etc above the specific job
jobname:
  variables:
    GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE: 1
# More job declarations, etc.
```

The "smudge" process replaces the link/pointers to the LFS files with the actual files.  By telling GitLab's CI job to skip the smudge, the LFS files aren't downloaded.

Placing `GIT_LFS_SKIP_SMUDGE: 1` in a variables section at the top may make it apply to all of the defined jobs.